# Creditmemo - Custom refund amount PER product

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo

I'm working on Magento Credit-memo. I want to Refund product BUT with custom price INSTEAD of product's price.

[image]

Here I've added a Column for Entering a Custom refund price.

Can any one suggest, what the next STEP should be ?

Comment: you also get questions :-)

Comment: Yes, why not ? I'm a programmer at least, LIKE you :-)

Comment: haha, true you are genius programmer, i'm copy paster :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is, why would you need to do this?

If you need to subtract an amount away from the refund, such as a restocking fee, then why not just populate the restocking fee box.

If you need to refund more, use the additional refund box.

Otherwise you're on the road to giving yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: scenario here is, if customer is returning product then store owner offers him a discount, say 30% on product price, So I need to refund ONLY 30% to the customer

Comment: Then really what's happening here is. The item is being returned in full and the customer is being given a store credit to use.

Comment: No, actually item is not being returned. Customer keep it with him BUT with discounted amount. So I need to refund that discounted amount